# WMS USGS/ortho links going bad

Tags: wms, usgs

New QGIS user, 2.6 Brighton.  Periodically my WMS links to USGS terrain (typical contour) and ortho-imagery just go bad and give me the following view.  This has happened before, but not for a while.  Any thoughts on this?  Can't get them to renew - just get the checkerboard image for both.  I'm online, all other web / other links working just fine. I've not done anything or altered the project in any form on last or current opening.

(24 hrs later...still no resolution to this...ortho-imagery link works just fine. USGS terrain will not show up.)

[image: "checkerboard" image from WMS link(s)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USGS WMS services appeared to have intermittent issues lasting from March 3rd through March 9th.

They acknowledged the issue on March 4th:

[image]

And declared it fixed on March 9th:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Oddly, I still have this issue going on with both USGS and ortho...March 13th.

Comment: @Malamutte - Same here.  Not long after I replied to your question, they posted an update on Twitter that they still haven't 100% fixed the problem.

https://twitter.com/USGSTNM/status/575407678949720065